# Django generate URL from View

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I would like to know how to generate an URL from my View.

My url is

`url(r'^team/(?P<teamid>\d+)/wall/$', 'xxx.views.team_wall', name='team_wall'),`

How can i generate my url from the view ?

```
# Views.py
def myview(request):
    teamID= fields["id"] # ID for URL
    teams.append({"title":fields["title"],  "url":  "???"})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) in the views.

```
teams.append({"title":fields["title"] ,  
    "url": reverse("team_wall", {'teamid':teamID}))
```

I'm assuming `teamID` is the team id that can be passed to the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have renamed fieldId into teamID to be more explicit for future readers. PLS rename.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using "reverse" function:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
```